# md5sum for every file (with ll)

Tags: command-line, files, hashsum

I want output like this: `name` `size`  and `hash`:

```
myfile.txt 222M 24f4ce42e0bc39ddf7b7e879a
mynewfile.txt 353M a274613df45a94c3c67fe646
```

For `name` and `size` only I have

```
ll -h | awk '{print $9,$10,$11,$12,$5}'
```

But how can I get `hash` for every file? I tried:

`ll -h | awk '{print $9,$10,$11,$12,$5}' | md5sum`

But I get only one hash at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You should not parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), instead use this:

```
for f in * .*; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && \
    printf "%s %s %s\n" "$f" $(du -h -- "$f" | cut -f1) $(md5sum -- "$f" | cut -d' ' -f1)
done
```

- The `for` loop runs trough all files and directories in the current directory.

  - `[ -f "$f" ]` checks if it's a regular file
  - `printf "%s %s %s\n"` prints the arguments in the desired format.
  - `"$f"` the first argument is the filename
  - `du -h -- "$f" | cut -f1` the second is the size (human readable), but not the filename, `cut` cuts all excep the first field away
  - `md5sum -- "$f" | cut -d' ' -f1` third is the MD5 sum, but without the filename.

Comment: Thank you! But how fix this for file names with spaces?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich See my edit

Comment: i would also suggest using tab as the field separator `"%s\t%s\t%s\n"` so that spaces in the filename can be distinguished from the field-separators.  Of course, filenames can contain tabs too but they'e far less common - no easy way to create them.

Comment: If this output might get re-parsed, maybe use a "/" field separator, as that can't show up in a file name.